# How To Add og:price:amount to Magento

Tags: php, magento, facebook-opengraph

I've managed to add other open graph tags to our Magento head, but having no luck displaying the price.

The page breaks if I add code such as:

meta property="og:price:amount" content="currency($finalPrice, true, false); ?>" /

The price also needs to be stripped of the currency symbol.

Page example:
http://www.discountdisplays.co.uk/html/contemporary-bar-stool.html

Any help would be much appreciated.

SOLUTION

I managed to get the correct price using the following code:

```
<meta property="og:price:amount" content="<?php echo Mage::registry('product')->getFinalPrice(); ?>" />
```

Comment: `The page breaks` is not a good problem description. Please look into your `/path/to/magento/var/log/` and `exception.log` or `system.log` if you can find any other useful information. Additionally are you sure you wrote `content="currency($finalPrice, ...); ?>"`? Thats wrong then and probably already the source of your error. Try `content="<?=currency($finalPrice, true, false);?>"` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
  Mage::registry('current_product')->getFinalPrice(); ?>
```

Instead of

```
   Mage::registry('product')->getFinalPrice(); ?>
```

This will get the current product.

Answer (score 0):

Use  the below once

```
$_coreHelper = Mage:;helper('core');

    $finalPrice= $_coreHelper->currency(Mage::registry('current_product')
->getFinalPrice(),false,true);
```

This code will give you amount of porduct